# clang-format: Do not add white spaces to include statement/method references

Tags: code-formatting, clang-format

I'm using [`clang-format`](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) to format code.

I noticed that it adds white spaces to include statements and fully qualified method references.

Given the following ("correctly formatted") piece of code:

```
#include bli/bla/blub/_foo;

fun()
{
    bli/bla/blub/_foo::bar();
}
```

When running it through `clang-format`, it turns it into this:

```
#include bli / bla / blub / _foo;

fun() { bli / bla / blub / _foo::bar(); }
```

I do not want the spaces to be added before and after the `/` since the path may not be modified. The curly bracket placements don't matter.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, I've taken a look at the documentation [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) but I didn't see a respective `style` option. Any ideas/help on fixing this?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, what programming language is your code written in? :-)

Answer (score 1):

That code is not valid C++, so clang-format doesn't behave the way you might expect (I'm assuming C++ is what you're going for).

- The statement `#include bli/bla/blub/_foo;` should have double quotes before and after the header path, and the semicolon omitted.
- For fully qualifying symbols in C++, you have to use `::` for the seperator, so `bli/bla/blub/_foo::bar();` is not valid C++, either.

In the include statement, since double quotes are missing, clang-format sees `bli/bla/blub/_foo` as "`bli` divided by `bla` divided by `blub` divided by `_foo::bar()`" - just as any C/C++ compiler would - and adds spaces between `/` and the operands, which seems sensible.

If you feed clang-format with proper C++ code, for example:

```
#include "bli/bla/blub/_foo"

void fun()
{
    bli::bla::blub::_foo::bar();
}
```

You'd get:

```
#include "bli/bla/blub/_foo"

void fun() {
  bli::bla::blub::_foo::bar();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. I was working with a C++ dialect so I assume using `clang-format` on that won't work that well. The syntax is correct however.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza got it. `clang-format` auto detects that syntax to be C++, but you may be able to customize it the way that fits your needs. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an option to avoid inserting spaces between a binary operator and its operands, i.e. `a/b` is always transformed into `a / b`.